# Unable to use file endpoint in Mule on Linux server

Tags: linux, mule-component, file-connection

Everytime I try to poll network drive on linux machine, it gets failed. I've tried both the options giving the absolute path and the mount path of the network drive. It is specifically giving errors when my Mule Runtime is also on Linux, on Windows it is working perfectly fine. Here is my flow:

I've also tried path="/ihr_dev_test/Dev/Ingest_Storage/Practitioner", since ihr_dev_test is mounted on my linux server, but every time I get the same error:

I'm running my Mule workflow on linux Machine, following is the Stacktrace:

2017-12-18 06:08:47,639 [qtp100710435-9788] INFO  org.mule.transport.file.FileConnector - Registering listener: filepollerFlow on endpointUri: file:///nasv0053.uhc.com/ihr_dev_test/Dev/Ingest_Storage/Practitioner
2017-12-18 06:08:47,640 [qtp100710435-9788] INFO  org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager - Initialising: 'null'. Object is: FileMessageReceiver

---

Message               : Failed to start inbound endpoint "endpoint.file.nasv0053.uhc.com.ihr.dev.test.Dev.Ingest.Storage.Practitioner"
Element               : /endpoint.file.nasv0053.uhc.com.ihr.dev.test.Dev.Ingest.Storage.Practitioner @ app:filepoller.xml:10 (File)
Exception stack is:
Failed to start inbound endpoint "endpoint.file.nasv0053.uhc.com.ihr.dev.test.Dev.Ingest.Storage.Practitioner" (org.mule.api.lifecycle.LifecycleException)
  org.mule.util.FileUtils.openDirectory(FileUtils.java:128)
 org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver.doConnect(FileMessageReceiver.java:155)
 org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.connectHandler(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:448)

Comment: You have better chance to solve your problem if you ask on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: You should provide more info. Are you running Mule on this linux machine or somewhere else ? If it's "somwhere else", can you access the files on the linux machine outside Mule, and how did you mount that file system ? Does the Mule user have permission to access the mount point ? Remember to post the whole stacktrace, not just a part of it, and perhaps copy/paste the Mule configuration you have.

Comment: I'm running my Mule workflow on linux Machine, following is the Stacktrace: